# ¿La instrucción "del" puede eliminar más de un ítem en una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Según lo que voy entendiendo, la instrucción "del" solo puede eliminar un ítem, así como también a una variable completa con todos sus ítem en lista. Pero me pregunté si existe la manera de eliminar más de un ítem de una lista y me encontré con este ejemplo en otra página.

```
>>> a = [1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
>>> del a[2:4]
>>> a
[1, 66.25, 1234.5]
```

No comprendo el significado de los dos puntos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` es el delimitador de la sintaxis de *slice* (rebanada, rodaja, porción), que sirve para  extraer sub-partes de iterables (listas, cadenas) y está dada de la forma `[inicio:fin]` (de la sección que queremos realizar).

- `[1:5]` es equivalente a "de 1 a 5", el 5 no está incluido.
- `[3:]` es equivalente a "de 3 hasta el final"

Los slices soportan expresiones, por lo que se podrían utilizar variables, por ejemplo.

Dicho esto, `a[2:4]` es la *porción* formada por los elementos *"del 2 al 4, sin incluír el 4"*, lo que se traduce a los elementos `a[2]` y `a[3]`.